# Angular Mat-select default selection

Tags: angular

This is the select I have for the year, I need the current year to be selected by default and then collect that data in the back.

This is the html:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
                    <mat-select #selectedYear placeholder="Year" formControlName="yearUser">
                        <mat-select-search [matSelect]="selectedYear"></mat-select-search>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">{{ year }}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

This is the ts:

```
selectedYear: number;
years: number[] = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private msgs: MessageService,
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private dashboardService: DashboardService,
    private router: Router,
    private uiUtils: UIUtilsService,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
  ) { 

    this.selectedYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (let year = this.selectedYear; year >= 2020; year--) {
      this.years.push(year);
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Default selection for mat-select in case you are using reactive forms is done via FormControl.

const control = new FormControl('some value');

For more information check FormControl API https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: I am starting to program with Angular and I have no experience at all. I used the attribute ``selected`` in the select. But now I don't know how to apply it with Angular and the mat-select. And excuse me but I don't understand the FormControl API

Comment: First of all you need to know basics of Angular. You can find good official documentation on the official site Angular.io. Read it carefully - this is very important.

Comment: Okay great thanks, if it is what I am with now I have the angular documentation always close. You could still solve the problem I have with the default value, I am getting very stuck and I cannot continue.

Comment: To solve the problem I need to see FormBuilder in your component

Comment: You mean the import? That's the one I have: ``import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';``

Comment: No, I mean the initialisation of the form.

Comment: Ok, I put a new comment with what I'm adding

Comment: yearUser: new Date().getFullYear()  - new Date is the default selection

Comment: Ok, so I need to put that value now in ngmodel right? It would be like this?  ``<mat-select #selectedYear placeholder="Year" formControlName="yearUser" [ngModel]="yearUser">``

Comment: This platform is for exact questions. This is not the right platform to learn. And answer to your question is - no.